# send email automatically at specific date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email

I'm implementing an email reminder to remind the student of returning the books before expired date.

I know Window Service can achieve that but since the machine will have restriction for installing the Window Service, so is there any other ideas?

Comment: Install it on a machine that has the capabilities that you require.

Comment: MVC Scheduled/Background Tasks are what you're looking for. And, when googled, shows [a stackoverflow blog entry on this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a Windows service to perform background tasks, just use Windows scheduled tasks. You can write an exe or batch file and schedule it as frequently as you like.

If the server won't let you run scheduled tasks, you can always create the task as an action in a MVC controller and create a scheduled task on another machine that calls your action.

Comment: Or as I call it, implement rube goldberg service architecture.

Comment: @asawyer - :) It's a bit Goldbergian, but if you don't have full access to the server (such as a cheap hosting environment), you start running out of options. It can be a big leap for some to go to a dedicated server environment.